# jsdoc self executing anonymous function

Tags: module, jsdoc

How can i document a module like this with jsdoc? I tried many version, but can't get it work. Funciton test doesn't appear in the documentation.

```
/**
 * Description of module, defines module for whole file
 *    
 * @module constructors
 * @exports app
 */


var app = (function() {
    /**
     * Description of function test
     */
    function test() {
        return '';
    }

    return {
        test: test
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of version 3.2.2, jsdoc is easily tripped by modules, the solution is to use `module:` with the module name to specify where the entity you are documenting resides:

```
/**
 * Description of module, defines module for whole file
 *
 * @module constructors
 */

var app = (/** @lends module:constructors */ function() {
    /**
     * Description of function test
     */
    function test() {
        return '';
    }

    return {
        test: test
    }
}());
```

Comment: It works with version 3.2.2 but with the newest version it doesn't work, function test isn't provided in the documentation. Did the syntax of JSDoc change?

Comment: Don't use 3.3.0. It is alpha, and buggy. I don't know yet whether there are syntax changes introduced by 3.3.0.

Comment: Glad to help! :) I see from having checked your profile that you are new on Stack Overflow. The best way to thank someone who solved your problem is to mark their answer as accepted, and vote it up. You cannot vote my answer up because you do not have enough reputation but you can accept it. Besides any reputation gains, it helps third parties to know that this question has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

For me, using JSDoc 3.4.0 helped this solution:

```
/**
 * @module array-cop
 */

/**
* @function
* @name Anonymous self-invoked function
* @description Call main module
* @param {Object} this Window for the browser
*/

(function(_) {

    var array_ = {
      /**
      * @function
      * @name check
      * @description Method for checking type of the source data.
      * @param {Array} arr  Source data.
      * @returns {Boolean} Returns true if Array.isArray, otherwise throw error.
      * @throws Will throw an error "Not an array" if the argument isn't array.
      */
        check: function(arr) {
            return Array.isArray(arr) || (function() {
                throw new Error("Not an array!");
            }());
        },

// Some code stuff

    /**
     * npm / <script> compatibility
     */

    if (typeof module !== "undefined" && module.exports) {
        module.exports = array_;
    } else {
        _.array_ = array_;
    }
}(this));
```

and also I created gulp task for generate JSDoc documentation:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    child_exec = require('child_process').exec;

// Task for generationg JSDoc
gulp.task('docs', function(done) {

    var settings = {
      docGenerator: "./node_modules/jsdoc/jsdoc.js",
      srcFile: "./src/array-cop.js",
      jsDocConfPath: "./jsdoc.json",
      docsOutputPath: "./docs"
    }

    child_exec('node '
                + settings.docGenerator
                + ' ' + settings.srcFile
                + ' -c ' + settings.jsDocConfPath
                + ' -d ' + settings.docsOutputPath, undefined, done);
});
```

after running `gulp docs`
documentation will be placed to the `./docs` folder

Comment: That's not how you're supposed to use the @name tag: http://usejsdoc.org/tags-name.html